# Using MSAL Python/Django, how do I get Authenticated event?

Tags: python, django, azure-ad-msal

I have a working Django app that uses the MSAL library ms-identity-python-utilities@main.  I can successfully sign in to Azure AD.  I need to however load the local user object from my database on successful sign in, like I used to do in my old /login URL endpoint, to call auth_login(request, user).  This should happen after the OAuth2 flow succeeded.  Intent is to use OAuth2 as SSO.

How do I intercept this event?  I.e. after successful OAuth2 authentication, call a method that can call auth_login(request, user) and set the user object into the session for future use?

I could not find any references in the samples / forums.

`@ms_identity_web.login_required`  works to ensure authentication for views, but I want a decorator or class I can extend to intercept signed on event.